# JavaScript keyboard event handler for long press

Tags: javascript, keyboard, dom-events

I want to get `keyup` and `keydown` events with JavaScript, the problem is that at a long keyboard press those events are triggered automatically very often. Could I access the keys directly to get the physical events?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyup is fired once the key is released and the default action was performed. Keydown will repeat while key is not depressed.

So you can make an action the first time the keydown event is handled, and not doing it again until the keyup event was fired.

```
var action = true;

input.addEventListener('keydown', function () {
  if (action === true) {
    action = false;
    // do your action here
  }
});

input.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  action = true;
});
```

Comment: Well you are right, I forgot that keyup of course is just fired once. Thank you!